# Regex to check a string contains just one word

Tags: c#, regex

I was shown the following:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\b*[a-zA-Z0-9_]\b", ErrorMessage = "Enter a single work account name please")]
```

But it seems to give an error when a string contains more than one character. Can someone help with a Regex that checks if there is more than one word in a string?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Check `if there is more than one word in a string` or check `when a string contains more than one character`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was only missing one single piece to your regex

```
 @"^\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b$"
```

you forgot to state that the character could be repeated more than 1 time. That's the reason for the plus sign, so that it may accept only 1 word

Comment: This does *not* satisfy the requirement that only one word is allowed. Pass "foo bar" and you get two matches. You need `^…$` instead of word boundaries `\b`.

Answer (score 12):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

Word boundaries `\b` do not work here, as the pattern will match for each word.

If you want to allow non-Latin characters, you can use the shorthand version:

```
^\w+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\b"`. This will match any of those characters one or more times.

Comment: This does *not* satisfy the requirement that only one word is allowed. Pass "foo bar" and you get two matches. You need `^…$` instead of word boundaries `\b`.